# Python Iterating and Creating a Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

I have some data that is in the below format (mylist) and I am trying to convert it into a nested dictionary but struggling to get the format correct. I've tried several variations of iterations and transformations but can't get the desired result. Can I get some help getting the data in desired format as shown in the desired result using the data format in mylist?

```
mylist = [
    [('floor', 'first_floor'), ('bed_room', 'room1'), ('windows', 2), ('color', 'violet')],
    [('floor', 'second_floor'), ('bed_room', 'room2'), ('windows', 4), ('color', 'violet')],
]

nest_keys = ['floor', 'bedroom']
cmd_tree = {}
for i in mylist:
    last_element = True
    for key in reversed(nest_keys):
        if last_element is True:
            cmd_tree = {key: dict([x for x in i if x[0] not in nest_keys])}
            last_element = False
        else:
            cmd_tree = {key: cmd_tree}

print(cmd_tree)
```

**Current Result:**

```
{'floor': {'bedroom': {'bed_room': 'room2', 'windows': 4, 'color': 'violet'}}}
```

**Desired Result:**

```
{'floor': {'first_floor': {'bed_room': {'room1': {'color': 'white',
                                                  'windows': 2}}},
           'second_floor': {'bed_room': {'room2': {'color': 'violet',
                                                   'windows': 4}}}}}
```

Comment: `'windows'` is before `'color'` in `mylist`, Are you sure you want it after the `'color'` in the desired output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to loop in reverse, loop through the list and each initial iteration is a floor, then loop through it's contents to create the floors details:

```
result = {}
br = 'bed_room'

for (_, floor_name), *details in mylist:
    result[floor_name] = {br: {}}
    
    for name, detail in details:
        if name == br:
            room = detail
            result[floor_name][br][room] = {}
        else:
            result[floor_name][br][room][name] = detail

print({'floor': result})
```

---

```
{'floor': {'first_floor': {'bed_room': {'room1': {'color': 'violet',
                                                  'windows': 2}}},
           'second_floor': {'bed_room': {'room2': {'color': 'violet',
                                                   'windows': 4}}}}}
```

Comment: thank you for very much for the response. Can I ask what does the "_," and the *details do in the for loop?

Comment: It's referred to as assignment unpacking. See: [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) for more details

Comment: If this has answered your question please feel free to mark it as so!

Comment: I get `KeyError: 2` in line : `result[floor_name][br][detail][name] = detail`. Are you sure this works ?

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary My mistake in cleaning up. I edited.

Comment: Working for me. But one one follow up.  If the keys were dynamic is there a way to use a reference list for columns that would be the unique keys?  In my example I was using `nest_keys = ['floor', 'bedroom']` as a reference because the number of elements could change.

Comment: @Jab Great. Now your output is correct while the desired output that OP requested is not in order (`'windows'` is after `'color'`).